# Error: DbContext has been disposed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext, jsonresult

```
public JsonResult JTask(int id)
{
    using (TestDb db = new TestDb())
    {
        var a = db.ToDos.Where(todo => todo.UserId == id);
        return Json(a, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I have a problem with returning `JsonResult`
When I run this code code I get the error

> "The operation cannot be completed because the `DbContext` has been
>   disposed."

I tried adding `.ToList()` at the end of the line 3, as was suggested, but then I got the error

> "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type
>   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies."

Comment: You will need the `ToList` on the end, because obviously the query won't execute until it gets *evaluated*. However, the reason you're getting a circular reference is I guess because you have a model which has a navigation property to another model which has one back. In this case, you need to set up MVC or WebApi JSON serialiser to ignore reference loops

Comment: How are you doing JSON serialising? Are you setting it up in the Global.asax or something?

Comment: Are you using Javascriptserializer or JSON.Net?

Comment: I have no idea how to do the serialization. :(

Comment: @KiokoKey JSON.NET library is capable of dealing with circular references, you should look up how to use it. But ideally you shouldn't have any circular references when you serialize by using DTO's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very obvious, but the built-in `Json` method only does the serialization after the `JTask` method has finished executing. By that time, of course, the context has been disposed, resulting in the original error you are describing.

If you have an `ICollection<TodoItem>` property inside your `Todo` class, each of those will have a `ToDo` property which is a reference back to the parent. And each of those `ToDo` properties will also have `ICollection<TodoItem>` children, which has a reference back to the parent again, and so on and so forth. This can potentially loop for infinity, and when the serializer tries to serialize the object, it gives up with a circular reference error.

One way to solve both of these problems at the same time is by using viewmodels. A viewmodel is an intermediate class that holds only a subset of the properties that a model class has. The typical flow is for the model class to get converted to a viewmodel first, then it would be the viewmodel that gets serialized as json:

```
var viewModels = new List<TodoViewModel>();

using (TestDb db = new TestDb())
{
    var todoModels = db.ToDos.Where(todo => todo.UserId == id).ToList();

    foreach (var model in todoModels)
    {
        var todoViewModel = new TodoViewModel
        {
            // Populate viewmodel properties here
            Text = model.Text
        };

        viewModels.Add(todoViewModel);
    }
}

return Json(viewModels, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I wrote a blog post about the advantages of using viewmodels. You can check it out here if you're interested: [Why Use ViewModels](http://www.ojdevelops.com/2016/05/why-use-viewmodels.html)

Comment: Thank you so much!:) You helped me a lot. I've been stuck on this for several hours:)

Comment: No problem. Welcome (back) to StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 1):

Because Linq is Lazy by the time the `JSON` tries to get the data out of `a` (and only then actually goes to `db`) the `db` has already been disposed - when leaving the scope of the `using`

```
public JsonResult JTask(int id)
{
    using (TestDb db = new TestDb())
    {
        var a = db.ToDos.Where(todo => todo.UserId == id).ToList();
        return Json(a, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: IEnumerables can be lazy, this isn't the whole answer though

Comment: Now I have the problem with "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type"
Can you help mi with serialization? I'm not sure how to do it the proper way

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = db.ToDos.Where(todo => todo.UserId == id).ToList();
```